Springboot 6.1 AuthenticationEntryPoint has been marked for removal , how to implement its mechnism in my code
@Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)throws Exception{
       httpSecurity
               .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsService,jwtTokenHelper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
               .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
               .authorizeHttpRequests((request)->{
                   request
                   .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().authenticated();
               })
               .sessionManagement((session)-> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
               .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);
       return httpSecurity.build();
   }

Above is SecurityFilterChain code , in springboot 6 where to add AuthenticationEntryPoint or any other ways to achieve same goal?

Dont hand out JWTs to browsers, its dangerous. None of this code is from the docs, this code is from a bad blog, that has no idea how security works. Read the official docs and implement proper security.

Thanks for input ,any official way docs link that explains well?

why not look in the official docs... there is a chapter named JWT..... .....
